# send crash log from app?

Tags: iphone, crash, logging

I am working on an iPhone app and wondering if I should include a way to send the crash log from the users phone to me if needed.

I have included this on an Android app I made and it helped quite a bit when the app was first released.

Interested to know what everyone thinks?  Do I need to find a way to do this in the iPhone?  If so does anyone have any examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user granted iTunes to do it on a sync, Apple will collect them and publish them in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com)

Answer (score 0):

Also look at - http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/